# Volume rendering in vtk(python) using low data of grid

Tags: python, vtk, volume-rendering

I would like to do volume rendering in vtk(python) using low data of grid and scalar values.

The Data which I have is like below

```
#{
#   "Field Quantity": "p(x,y,z,f)"
#   "Field Quantity Units": "Pa"
#   "Snapshot Quantity": "Frequency"
#   "Snapshot Value": 10000
#   "Snapshot Units": "Hz"
#   "Column 1 Quantity": "x"
#   "Column 1 Units": "m"
#   "Column 2 Quantity": "y"
#   "Column 2 Units": "m"
#   "Column 3 Quantity": "z"
#   "Column 3 Units": "m"
#   "Column 4-5 Quantity": "Re/Im Pressure"
#   "Column 4-5 Units": ""
#   "Number Rows": 48
#}
-2.5000000000e-003  -2.5000000000e-003  1.5000000000e-003   8.9377240003e-020   3.8721174272e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -2.5000000000e-003  1.5000000000e-003   -9.1717825094e-020  -3.9798318526e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -2.5000000000e-003  1.5000000000e-003   9.1171769567e-020   4.0357725265e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -2.5000000000e-003  1.5000000000e-003   -8.9922526510e-020  -3.8161699679e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  -1.5000000000e-003  1.5000000000e-003   9.0017374399e-020   3.8911280410e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -1.5000000000e-003  1.5000000000e-003   -9.2372396377e-020  -3.9998715954e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -1.5000000000e-003  1.5000000000e-003   9.1826276227e-020   4.0557825425e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -1.5000000000e-003  1.5000000000e-003   -9.0563145582e-020  -3.8351773505e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  -5.0000000000e-004  1.5000000000e-003   9.0017820301e-020   3.8911018685e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -5.0000000000e-004  1.5000000000e-003   -9.2372545011e-020  -3.9998454229e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -5.0000000000e-004  1.5000000000e-003   9.1826315001e-020   4.0557818963e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -5.0000000000e-004  1.5000000000e-003   -9.0562932325e-020  -3.8351886597e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  5.0000000000e-004   1.5000000000e-003   8.9376878111e-020   3.8721167810e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  5.0000000000e-004   1.5000000000e-003   -9.1717663535e-020  -3.9798851670e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  5.0000000000e-004   1.5000000000e-003   9.1171659707e-020   4.0357857743e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   5.0000000000e-004   1.5000000000e-003   -8.9922416650e-020  -3.8161906474e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  -2.5000000000e-003  2.5000000000e-003   8.9725437804e-020   3.8824497532e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -2.5000000000e-003  2.5000000000e-003   -9.2073900498e-020  -3.9907483749e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -2.5000000000e-003  2.5000000000e-003   9.1527657564e-020   4.0466754778e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -2.5000000000e-003  2.5000000000e-003   -9.0271053891e-020  -3.8265142492e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  -1.5000000000e-003  2.5000000000e-003   9.0368493182e-020   3.9015298373e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -1.5000000000e-003  2.5000000000e-003   -9.2731211817e-020  -4.0107881177e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -1.5000000000e-003  2.5000000000e-003   9.2184755625e-020   4.0667446243e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -1.5000000000e-003  2.5000000000e-003   -9.0914167430e-020  -3.8455775312e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  -5.0000000000e-004  2.5000000000e-003   9.0368480257e-020   3.9015194975e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -5.0000000000e-004  2.5000000000e-003   -9.2730888700e-020  -4.0107984575e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -5.0000000000e-004  2.5000000000e-003   9.2184787937e-020   4.0667200674e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -5.0000000000e-004  2.5000000000e-003   -9.0914225591e-020  -3.8455720382e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  5.0000000000e-004   2.5000000000e-003   8.9725754459e-020   3.8824584774e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  5.0000000000e-004   2.5000000000e-003   -9.2073939272e-020  -3.9907257567e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  5.0000000000e-004   2.5000000000e-003   9.1527748036e-020   4.0466509209e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   5.0000000000e-004   2.5000000000e-003   -9.0271047429e-020  -3.8265126336e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  -2.5000000000e-003  3.5000000000e-003   8.9376981509e-020   3.8721439229e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -2.5000000000e-003  3.5000000000e-003   -9.1717960803e-020  -3.9798441311e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -2.5000000000e-003  3.5000000000e-003   9.1171452912e-020   4.0357815738e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -2.5000000000e-003  3.5000000000e-003   -8.9922507123e-020  -3.8161783690e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  -1.5000000000e-003  3.5000000000e-003   9.0017632893e-020   3.8911241636e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -1.5000000000e-003  3.5000000000e-003   -9.2372435151e-020  -3.9998505928e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -1.5000000000e-003  3.5000000000e-003   9.1826114668e-020   4.0557731721e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -1.5000000000e-003  3.5000000000e-003   -9.0562912938e-020  -3.8351615178e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  -5.0000000000e-004  3.5000000000e-003   9.0017445485e-020   3.8911209325e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  -5.0000000000e-004  3.5000000000e-003   -9.2372305904e-020  -3.9998441305e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  -5.0000000000e-004  3.5000000000e-003   9.1826256840e-020   4.0557844812e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   -5.0000000000e-004  3.5000000000e-003   -9.0563074496e-020  -3.8352038462e-020  
-2.5000000000e-003  5.0000000000e-004   3.5000000000e-003   8.9377091369e-020   3.8721109649e-020   
-1.5000000000e-003  5.0000000000e-004   3.5000000000e-003   -9.1717986653e-020  -3.9798460698e-020  
-5.0000000000e-004  5.0000000000e-004   3.5000000000e-003   9.1171782492e-020   4.0357809276e-020   
5.0000000000e-004   5.0000000000e-004   3.5000000000e-003   -8.9922468349e-020  -3.8161635056e-020
```

Data was constructed as 5 columns. 
1,2,3 columns is x,y,z coordination of grid.

4 column is real parts of complex number and 5 column is imaginary parts of complex number.
I made absolute value using 2 columns (4,5 columns) as scalar values.

Thus I tried to do volume rendering like below.
There is no error, but nothings come up in vtk window
In my opinion, there seems to be a problem in UnStructuredGrid, vtkDataSetTriangleFilter

```
import vtk
import numpy as np

readtxt = np.genfromtxt("ExportedFieldData.txt",skip_header=16,comments='%', missing_values='1.#QNAN00000e+000')
re = readtxt[:,3]
re[np.isnan(re)] = 0

im = readtxt[:,4]
im[np.isnan(im)] = 0

p = np.abs(re+1j*im)

print(p[2])
max_p = max(p)
print(max_p)
x = readtxt[:,0]
y = readtxt[:,1]
z = readtxt[:,2]

points = vtk.vtkPoints()
ugrid = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGrid()

pressure = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
pressure.SetNumberOfTuples(len(x))

for i in range(len(x)):
    points.InsertNextPoint(x[i], y[i], z[i])
    pressure.SetValue(i, p[i])


ugrid.SetPoints(points)
ugrid.GetPointData().SetScalars(pressure)

trifilter = vtk.vtkDataSetTriangleFilter()
trifilter.SetInputData(ugrid)

volumeMapper = vtk.vtkOpenGLProjectedTetrahedraMapper()
volumeMapper.SetInputConnection(trifilter.GetOutputPort())

opacityTransferFunction = vtk.vtkPiecewiseFunction()
opacityTransferFunction.AddPoint(10000, 0.2)
opacityTransferFunction.AddPoint(200000, 1.0)

colorTransferFunction = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()
colorTransferFunction.AddRGBPoint(10000, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
colorTransferFunction.AddRGBPoint(200000, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

volumeProperty = vtk.vtkVolumeProperty()
volumeProperty.SetColor(colorTransferFunction)
volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacity(opacityTransferFunction)
volumeProperty.SetScalarOpacityUnitDistance(300)
volumeProperty.ShadeOff()

volume = vtk.vtkVolume()
volume.SetMapper(volumeMapper)
volume.SetProperty(volumeProperty)


ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
ren.AddVolume(volume)

renderer_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
renderer_window.AddRenderer(ren)

style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()


interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderer_window)
interactor.SetInteractorStyle(style)
interactor.Initialize()
interactor.Start()





print(len(x))
print(readtxt)
print(p)
```

So, I really appreciate if you let me know the solution of this problem  :)
what I want to make,,

[image]